# Can I link to ROS libraries without CMAKE?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everytime I try to use a library built by CMAKE, I need to also use CMAKE.  I don't want to use CMAKE.  I just want to use the LIB, INCLUDEPATH, and DEPENDPATH variables in my Qt project.  Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270794/can-i-link-to-ros-libraries-without-cmake?/) by [drhalftone](https://answers.ros.org/users/31874/drhalftone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-09-12**:
Please consider rephrasing this in a way that does not read as an attack on cmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This post http://jbohren.com/tutorials/2014-02-10-roscpp-hello-world/#create-the-simplest-ros-c-program describes what catkin and cmake are doing under the hood, and how to build a simple ROS node on the command line without cmake.

The ROS packages that you install through apt-get also install pkgconfig files in `/opt/ros/<distro>/lib/pkgconfig`, if your build system is compatible with pkgconfig.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3